# Android - how to store facebook login & normal user login data in database?

Tags: php, android, database, database-design, facebook-login

What is the best way to store facebook login + normal login?

Currently I have a `loginActivity`, where there is a `facebook login` button, a `normal login Email/Password Edittext fields` for normal login + '`register`' button for normal user registration

When someone clicked the facebook login button,

it will login with facebook api,
and then store the fb provided `username/fb_id/email` etc + `password` (`is actually the facebook email`) hashed with PHP `password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)` as '`registration`' and then '`login`' with the `email`

there is no registration for facebook accounts, the registration is automatic using the facebook email + auto generated password

while someone register with `register button` as normal user, it does almost the same thing, but storing user provided `username/password/email` to DB and then login with the `email`

is this the correct way to store users with FB login and Normal login?

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer, for me I will use Shared Preference, it serves as a session for the user. And by that (assuming I'm using phpMyAdmin) as my server, I will fetch the data / pass the data to my server by getting the values in the shared preference. Regarding about your DB, is it local? SQLite? 
.
Things to consider about fb API.

- if password is auto generated every time he log in, we cannot store that one.(It's up to you, but if you insist, use BIG INT). For this offer them to make their own password in your own app. Refer to the Facebook Doc Link.
- if a user has an unique id (fb id) we can store that one and also the email add and etc (data you requested).
  And compare those two in Sql server by using php code with sqli statement (Current user logged FB_ID && EMAIL).
- if your app required other info like first name, last name, and birth date you can get that one too. And compare all the data using php code with mysqli statement. But first pass those data from shared pref in background first to your server.

[Facebook Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/multiple-providers/) - Read here for more.

**Adding manual login info to a Facebook Login created account**

This situation occurs when someone creates their account in your app using Facebook Login, but later wants to also log in to the account using a unique credential and a password. For example, Netflix has a web app that uses Facebook Login alongside a regular login system, and also an Xbox 360 app where people can only use the regular login system.

1. Ensure the Facebook Login email address is verified

**If you use an email address as the unique credential which identifies each account, your app should verify that the email address associated with the person's Facebook account (and obtained during Facebook Login) is valid. You can do this by creating code in your app to send a verification email to the address obtained after Facebook Login** (you will probably need to have this step as part of your regular login system anyway).

2. **Ask the person to supply a new password** (and other credentials)

Once the email address is verified, you can now request that the person supplies a password, indicating to them that they can use this to log in to your app in future in conjunction with their email address. Once supplied, you can add this to the same part of your database where you are currently storing account information.

If your app's login system doesn't use an email address as the identification and uses something user-generated like a username instead, then you should also request that the person supplies this at the same time as a password.

Comment: I used shared preference to store session data like userid etc after login, currently, all my app facebook login only hash the fb e mail and use it as password, it is stored on the server, the login with fb will verify if the email and hashed password match, is tht secure?

Comment: Is it necessary to create a password for fb login? Since my password is just a hashed fb email, will this be a security issue in the future, when there will be online transactions?

Comment: I Updated the answer above.